# tflite uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, dart, tflite

I've used tflite package about one year ago and then it gone deprecated because of lack of android V2 embedding, then I used tfltie_flutter package but now its also seems deprecated giving error,

```
The plugin `tflite_flutter` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?
I've tried to follow the documentation to migrate project to android v2 embedding but couldn't find mentioned files in the plugin's folder (the documentation must be for projects not packages).
If there's nothing I can do with this package using latest flutter sdk, suggest me one for using `tflite` model image classification

Comment: No, you probably cannot as a package user. But you can try to open a pull request in the package repository to fix this, or at least post an issue. Tried to find this error for this specific package but didn't find anything.

Comment: There are tons of issues and PRs in that repo already